# convert excel file to html and javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

i have one excel calculator file which contains several sheets and formulas searching across sheets.

i want to convert this calculator in html page, and using javascript to do the calculation.
I've built up mySQL database to store these data for lookups...using php forms should get user inputs

I am concerned with the logic and layout in excel is not so straightforward as in javascript using functions.

Is there a way to do this that ensures the accuracy?

Comment: nice try for converting excel to html using javascript.
Here is the solution to converting excel to html view using [here](http://codebeautify.org/excel-to-html)

Comment: May help others: I just found out this website: https://www.publisheet.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this once. Basically you have to get two things right. The html and the Javascript to compute the formulas :D. To generate the html from the excel I recommend saving the Excel sheet as a web page and study the generated html. You can use it as it is, modify it, or you feel brave enough, try to build a generator yourself. It will be hard to build a generator, it took me about 1.5 months to get all the quirks right.

The formulas are pretty tough as well. In your case, probably you need to translate a couple of formulas, which can be done by hand. Just assign an unique id to each td in the html (it can be the cellId from excel, like R30), and translate the formulas to JS. To mimic the excel cells, you can place input[type=text] tags in the editable tds.

To make a generic formula translator, that works with all formulas is a lot harder. I used ANTLR with an excel grammar. ANTLR then generates a lexer/parser and with the extracted AST we can finally get Javascript formulas. Took another 3 weeks to get everything right.

Comment: thanks for these inputs!!! so i guess there is no tools to do it then. just have to make sure to convert each Vlookup and hlookup correctly =)

Comment: @BigGirl1017 Here's something to help you: http://excelformulabeautifier.com/ . It should a lot easier with this (select translate to Javascript from the drop down).

Answer (score -3):

You can not run an xls file on a website, unless you have a program like Excel, which can be run as a CGI program. (IOW

Comment: thanks for your inputs. you're definitely right about running excel on website. however, i am trying to mimic the same calcultion, which can be a bit tricky since it involves many cells and sheets.